# Show all Wikidata descendants, uniquely

Tags: recursion, unique, sparql, wikidata

I have the following [working query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FitemLabel%29%20AS%20%3FitemLabel%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fsubclass%29%20as%20%3Fsubklass%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FsubclassLabel%29%20AS%20%3FsubLabel%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ3314483%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP279%20%3Fsubclass%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0Agroup%20by%20%3Fitem) with the aim of showing all subclasses of Q3314483 [1]:

```
SELECT ?item (SAMPLE(?itemLabel) AS ?itemLabel) (SAMPLE(?subclass) as ?subklass) (SAMPLE(?subclassLabel) AS ?subLabel) WHERE {
   ?item wdt:P279* wd:Q3314483 ;
         wdt:P279 ?subclass .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
group by ?item
```

The SAMPLE and GROUP pattern is designed to make the items unique. It seems to work, however the label columns are blank. How can they be displayed?

1. [Based on this](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-all-descendant-sub-classes-of-an-entity-in-Wikidata-I-e-not-just-the-direct-sub-classes-but-also-the-sub-sub-classes-sub-sub-sub-classes-etc-by-extension-all-ancestor-super-classes-as-well)

Comment: https://w.wiki/8gn, https://w.wiki/8go

Comment: That works (assuming labels are unique by ID), but omits the 3rd and 4th columns

Comment: `SELECT ?item (SAMPLE(?itemLabel) AS ?itemLabel) (SAMPLE(?subclass) as ?subklass) (SAMPLE(?subclassLabel) AS ?subLabel) WHERE {
   ?item wdt:P279* wd:Q3314483 ;
         wdt:P279 ?subclass .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". ?subclass rdfs:label         ?subclassLabel. ?item rdfs:label         ?itemLabel.}
}
group by ?item`

Comment: @AKSW That's the winner! Can you transfer it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AKSW in the comments. Answer is:

```
SELECT ?item (SAMPLE(?itemLabel) AS ?itemLabel) (SAMPLE(?subclass) as ?subklass) (SAMPLE(?subclassLabel) AS ?subLabel) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P279* wd:Q3314483 ;
  wdt:P279 ?subclass . SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". ?subclass rdfs:label ?subclassLabel. ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  }
}
GROUP BY ?item
```